# MySQL - Inner join not working with update statement

Tags: mysql

I have the below query which does not work, I don't know why as it seems to work with other similar queries. Could you tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
UPDATE `Student` 
SET Student.Half = 0
FROM `Student`
INNER JOIN `Year`
    on Student.GradYear = Year.GradYear
    and Year.UserID = 1
```

It should update the table and Half to 0, but it comes out with the error message 
" #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `Student` INNER JOIN `Year` on Student.GradYear = Year.GradYear and Ye' at line 3"

Comment: This is MySQL not SQL Server (MSSQL) @KamaleshM.Talaviya and comment “upvoters”

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

as per MySQL documentation your syntax itself is wrong 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE `Student` 
INNER JOIN `Year`
    on Student.GradYear = Year.GradYear
    and Year.UserID = 1
SET Student.Half = 0;
```

^this should work.